How to create JSON data correctly in C?
I'm implementing a secure HTTP client to Google Firebase Database for remote reading/writing sensor datas with STM32 using mbedTLS, LwIP and FreeRTOS. I followed  this example porting mbedTLS library to my application. The SSL connection with server is fine and i can successfully send GET request as below.
. Verifying peer X.509 certificate... ok
                                               > Write to server: 169 bytes written

GET /Command/TV1.json?auth=[DATABASE SECRET] HTTP/1.1
Host: ecu.firebaseio.com
Content-lenght: 0
Connection: Close

  < Read from server: 303 bytes read

                                    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2024 06:39:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 16
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

{"Status":"OFF"}

And the GET request body is sent with this code.
strcpy(path, "/LAB/Temperatures.json?auth=[Database Secret]");
len = sprintf((char*) buf, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        "Host: %s\r\n"
                        "Content-lenght: 0\r\n"
                        "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n", path, SERVER_NAME);

while((ret = mbedtls_ssl_write(&ssl, buf, len)) <= 0)
{
 if(ret != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_READ && ret != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_WRITE)
    {
    mbedtls_printf(" failed\n  ! mbedtls_ssl_write returned %d\n\n", ret);
    goto exit;
    }
}

But I think I have a problem with creating JSON data that i am sending to the server because my PUT request is returned with 400 bad request error as below.
. Setting up the SSL/TLS structure... ok

. Connecting to ecu.firebaseio.com at port: 443 ... ok

. Performing the SSL/TLS handshake... ok

. Verifying peer X.509 certificate... ok

 <Write to server: 272 bytes written

PUT /LAB/Temperatures.json?auth=[DATABASE SECRET] HTTP/1.1
Host: ecu.firebaseio.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Lenght: 75

{"Enclosure Temperatures" : "23.15", "MCU Temperatures" : "29.00"}

  < Read from server: 337 bytes read

                                    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2024 06:39:12 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 36
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

{
   "error" : "No data supplied."
                                }
                                  368 bytes read

                                                HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2024 06:39:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 150
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/source/ssl_msg.c:4681: mbedtls_ssl_fetch_input() returned -29312 (-0x7280)
                                                                                                             ../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/source/ssl_msg.c:4046: ssl_get_next_record() returned -29312 (-0x7280)


                                              EOF


sprintf(stringToProcess,"{\"Enclosure Temperatures\" : \"%.2f\", \"MCU Temperatures\" : \"%.2f\"}", enclosure_temp, mcu_temp);
strcpy(path, "/LAB/Temperatures.json?auth=[Database Secret]");

len = snprintf((char*) buf, sizeof(buf) -1,  "PUT %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                                                    "Host: %s\r\n"
                                                    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
                                                    "Content-Lenght: %d\r\n"
                                                    "\r\n"
                                                    "%s\r\n", path, SERVER_NAME, strlen(stringToProcess), stringToProcess);

while((ret = mbedtls_ssl_write(&ssl, buf, len)) <= 0)
{
 if(ret != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_READ && ret != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_WRITE)
    {
    mbedtls_printf(" failed\n  ! mbedtls_ssl_write returned %d\n\n", ret);
    goto exit;
    }
}

I tried the same request body structure with same path followed by Firebase DB secret using Python Request library and I can successfully write data to server with PUT request. For me I am not creating JSON data correctly for some reason and server responds HTTP 400 Bad Request.

hi. sprintf don't you want to use snprintf and strlcpy to protect agianst overflow? \"%.2f\", shouldn't this be a float, not a string? How to create JSON data correctly in C? Is this the question you want to ask, or do you want to interface with some api? Is this XY question? To create a JSON, use a library, like json-c. Don't you need to send \r\n on the end of http request?

hi @KamilCuk, thanks , i reorganized request with your advices and edited the question with new code. Response from server is same with HTTP 400.

You are getting a response from the server - you have ask the server why is it responding with that. Does it work when you use terminal on your pc? Then, find the difference. Find the documentation of the server you are trying to communicate with. The server knows why it responded with that particular error.

The reason you get 400 error because your path is incomplete and you forgot to add the authentication key to the sprint().

"Content-Lenght"?  This is what libcurl is for...

@KamilCuk confusing part is request is successful in other platforms with exactly same path and body structure.

@hcheung thanks for your reply, actually i did but didn't place here since DB secret is important

Thanks @AndrewHenle, you are right i have created a raw body request by myself, is there any reference that you know how to port libcurl to STM32 Cortex M3 environment?

@l.g.oasis, you should show what your actual code with a mask-out authentication key. The snprintf((char*) buf, sizeof(buf) -1,  "PUT %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nContent-Lenght: %d\r\n\r\n%s\r\n", path, SERVER_NAME, strlen(stringToProcess), stringToProcess); certain does not look like you had include the authentication key between path and SERVER_NAME and there is a typo in your Content-Lenght.
